# SharePoint Online : copy from existing list : issue with Column names

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, task-list, list-template, copy

I have an issue working with SharePoint Online. Because I do not have any tenant-wide admin rights, I can just use SharePoint site's settings and interface (no PnP :( ) to fulfill my client's needs.

**What I want :**

I want to create lists based on an existing "ActionTpl" list.
This template has renamed columns, column and view formatting.

**What we tried and what issue we met :**

1 - Creation of the Template list, called "ActionTpl".
I created it from the SP template "Work progress" (I think, in french it is displayed as "Suivi de la progression des travaux" :
[image]

This list has had some twirls done to it :

Column display names have been changed. For example, I renamed the "Work item" column to "Actions", by going to "list settings">clic on title column> change its display name > Save.

Formatting some columns to have a better User experience (mood barometre with emojis)
Formatting the default view to highlight painpoints.

2 - Creation of a new list from an existing one.
When the template list is ready, we create a new list (via button "New" > List) and click on "From existing list" :

[image: Create a list options]

For more info, see the [Official documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-new-list-based-on-the-columns-in-another-list-49666e8c-8c48-414f-8e5e-dc0e232acd27)

I named it ActionsTest. It is created and empty (ok behavior).

BUT the column names are not the good ones, they are the ones from the template list "Suivi de progression des travaux". For example, my "Actions" column is back to its old "Work item" display name.
The formatting seems to be okay though.

So now, each time I create a new list from the existing one "ActionTpl", I need to rename every column which has been turned back to its old self.. The problem is the user should be independant on these lists and renaming everything each time is quite time consuming.

**--- EDIT after @Callum comment ---**

I tried to create a template list from scratch, named it "Actions_Template".

I created custom columns in a column group.

I added formatting JSON to 2 of those columns (Progress and Priority), directly under their settings as I created it. I just copied the Json of other columns, using pill of choice.

I renamed the "Title" column to "Actions".
[image]

When creating a new List from Actions_Template, my custom columns are named perfectly.
BUT, Title is still Title, and the other standard columns I picked (ex Due Date and Assigned To) are in English...
[image: columns of the new list]

I don't understand, the regional settings are French :
[image: SharePoint regional settings]
Even my user account is in french :
[image: User account language settings]
Edge is under French too.

**------ EDIT END --------**

**Do you know why this behavior is happening ?
Do you know how I could copy from ActionTpl without having to rename every columns afterwards please ?**

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you tried creating a new list template and creating the columns with the correct names? e.g. you haven't renamed the columns in the template list

Comment: Thanks @CallumCrowley, I tried and edited my question with the new informations. TLDR : apparently the copy keeps the standard column names in English, and even though I've renamed some of my custom columns via their settings (and not via the list settings), it did not take it into account. Some formatting are not taken into account neither

Answer (score 0):

The standard columns names are by design, they will not be affected by the language settings. The language settings could only change the language in the command bar. However, the column names are determined when they are created or renamed. So in this case, you will need to rename the standard column names again.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Hi @Gaelle
Is this answer helpful for you? Please feel free to reply.